# concatenation with multiple quotes while displaying html using PHP

Tags: php, html, concatenation

Please assist in doing concatenation here

```
    echo"<form class='navbar-form navbar-left' role='search' method='POST' action='addr3.php'>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_delete" value="'.$id_r.'">
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'> I am Roaming </button>
    </form>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you dont use `'` and `"` in the same way, this should work:

```
echo "<form class='navbar-form navbar-left' role='search' method='POST' action='addr3.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='id_delete' value='".$id_r."'>
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'> I am Roaming </button>
</form>";
```

Comment: Thanks !! 
This works (y)

Answer (score 0):

Some `'`s are not correctly Used. Change this -

`value="'.$id_r.'"` to `value='" . $id_r . "'`

`type="hidden"` to `type='hidden'`

`name="id_delete"` to `name='id_delete'`

The whole code will be -

```
echo "<form class='navbar-form navbar-left' role='search' method='POST' action='addr3.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='id_delete' value='" . $id_r . "'>
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'> I am Roaming </button>
</form>";
```

Comment: While I do that in echo, any type of inverted commas get ended before $id_r leading to exclusion from the echo !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse your quotes.

```
<?php
echo '<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="POST" action="addr3.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_delete" value="'.$id_r.'">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> I am Roaming </button>
    </form>';
?>
```